# How to write unit test(s) for custom OutputStream

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, mockito, outputstream

I've had to create an `OutputStream` class (inspired by [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130527080241/http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Testing/jacareto/jacareto/toolkit/log4j/LogOutputStream.java.htm)) that writes to a logger instead of `stdout`, so I came up with the following:

```scala
case  class  OutputStreamLogger(level:  Level)  extends  OutputStream  {
    val  logger:  Logger  =  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("OutputStreamLogger")
    private  var  mem  =  ""

    /**
        *  Writes  byte  to  Logger,  flushes  automatically  at  EOL
        *
        *  @param  b  Int  Int  representation  of  character  to  get  written
        *
        *  @return  Unit
        */
    def  write(b:  Int):  Unit  =  {
        //  To  prevent  internal  conversion  from  byte  to  int
        val  bytes  =  new  Array[Byte](1)
        //  Get  least  significant  byte  from  int  argument
        bytes(0)  =  (b  &  0xff).toByte
        //  Turn  byte  array  into  String
        mem  +=  new  String(bytes)

        //  Automatically  flush  at  EOL
        if(mem.endsWith("\n"))  {
            //  Grab  everything  but  newline
            mem  =  mem.substring(0,  mem.length  -  1)
            //  Log  it
            flush()
        }
    }

    /**
        *  Sends  output  bytes  to  logger  at  specified  level
        *
        *  @return  Unit
        */
    override  def  flush():  Unit  =  {
        level  match  {
            //  Passing  the  format  then  the  String  eliminates
            //  need  to  check  if  logging  at  that  level  is  enabled
            case  Level.TRACE  =>  logger.trace("{}",  mem)
            case  Level.DEBUG  =>  logger.debug("{}",  mem)
            case  Level.INFO  =>  logger.info("{}",  mem)
            case  Level.WARN  =>  logger.warn("{}",  mem)
            case  Level.ERROR  =>  logger.error("{}",  mem)
        }
        //  Clear  out  buffer
        mem  =  ""
    }
}
```

How would I unit test this?  I've looked at other examples for unit testing `OutputStream`s, but they all use `PrintStream` where I would want to use my `OutputStreamLogger` and don't seem to be testing the `write` and `flush` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main testability issue with your output stream is probably this declaration:

```
val  logger:  Logger  =  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("OutputStreamLogger")
```

You have nailed the logger down to a concrete instance, where the initialization of that instance can not be customized. You can either now use a slf4j logging configuration during unit testing that writes to a temporary file and read that back. Maybe there is also a custom appender available that writes to an in memory buffer.

The other possibility is to change that declaration and allow a logger specification upon instance creation. You can then use this to inject a mock logger.

Testing then would just be writing something to the output stream and see if a newline flushes the output to the logger.

BTW - your implementation looks very inefficient as it creates a new string for every byte written. And having a local variable and a member with the same name is also confusing.

Comment: The local variable for `mem` was not supposed to be there and I'll fix the byte writing to not be so janky :) Allowing for the logger to be passed in definitely helped.  Thanks for the simplification and pointers!